# Get XML-ViewElement(MultiInput) byID in a controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5

In a XML-View there is defined a MultiInput like:

```
<MultiInput 
        placeholder="Tags"
        id="tagInput" 
        showValueHelp="false">
</MultiInput>
```

Now the Object need to be accessed in a function in a Controller. In the oninit function it works:

```
onInit: function() {
   var  multiInput  = this.getView().byId("tagInput")};
```

but it can´t be accessed in a other function like

```
onInit: function() {
   var  multiInput  = this.getView().byId("tagInput")},
otherFunction: function(){
   var view = this.getView(), // is null
   multiInput = sap.ui.getCore().byId("tagInput"), // is null
   multiInput1 = this.multiInput; // is null
};
```

I would like to us the multiInput in a SuccessHandler of a OdataRequest but i can´t get the MultiInput-Objekt ...

Comment: your 'otherFunction' is probably called before the view initialization :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.getView().byId()` is not the same as `sap.ui.getCore().byId()`. The first resolves IDs relative to the view (like *tagInput* in your case), the second only global IDs.

Perhaps you have lost the reference to `this`, too? In javascript `this` gets lost in callback functions. A common pattern is to declare `var that = this;` before the event handler and use `that.getView().byId()` instead.

UI5s attachEvent methods have an additional parameter to supply the object that will become `this` in the event handler.